# How to ensure all the objects of a Circular LinkedList are atleat traversed once without repetition in Java collections framework?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I have recently attended an interview on Java requirement and couldn't answer the following question:

How to ensure all the objects of a Circular LinkedList atleat are traversed atleast once without repetition of the same (object node) in Java collections framework?

Can someone please enlighten me on this?
Thank You in Advance..!

Comment: Same node or same value?

Answer (score 1):

If your LinkedList is made up of Strings, you could simply do this

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
//add items to list

for(String string : linkedList) {
    //string will loop though every string value in the linked list
}
```